# include <iostream> issue the application unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

When I started to use VS2013, I created just very basic application like this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello!";

    return 0;
}
```

It crashed and when I commented out the  `#include <iostream>` its no longer crash. I did several research on this error but nothing is suitable for my situation. This is the error :
[image]

Thanks for all your helps.

Comment: Rebuild the application with proper Runtime libraries.

Comment: Mostly, try this:: Goto Solution Property Page-> Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library :: Change that to "Multi-threaded" or rebuild the solution with /MT flag.

Comment: If you are building in "Debug" mode, then you can use "/MTd" flag for "Multi-threaded Debug"

Comment: Once you create a new project, if you create it as empty project I don't think you will face this issue. Also, you start it from scratch and you use int main() instead of that _tmain(...) and DO NOT use using namespace std;

Comment: thanks for your reply. I try your solution but it made another compile error  :
Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDKDDKVer.h': No such file or directory f:\vs2013project\staticfunction\staticfunction\targetver.h 8 1 StaticFunction

Comment: @FirstStep I tried to do that too. I created a empty project then used void main() ...  but it just the #include <iostream> made the program crashed.

Comment: int main() and not void main(). See my posted answer

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a new project, if you create it as an `empty project` I don't think you will face this issue. Then, you start it from scratch and you use `int main()` instead of that `_tmain(...)` and DO NOT EVER use `using namespace std;`

start a new EMPTY project and use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     std::cout << "Hello World";

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I just did what you suggest. Created empty then  coppied your code into mine, but it continue to show that error.

Comment: @user3819845 I am not sure but looks like you are missing some system files (static functions or dlls) for visual studio as a whole. If this is the case then repairing/reinstalling it will fix that

Comment: Thanks. That will be the last choice. I think maybe there are some mistakes that I can fix.